# Load different details on onClick of li in React

Tags: reactjs

In my application, I am displaying the character from a character.json file in li and when user click on particular li I am making an API request and fetching details of a movie and want to display, for that I am defining switch case for different li click and calling handleClick from componentDidMount() but I am getting an error. Can anyone suggest me how to fix that error and display data correctly?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import charactersFile from "./data/characters.json"
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    movies: [],
    loading: true,
    render: true
  }
  componentDidMount() {

  }

  handleClick = (character) => {
    console.log(character.name);
    const PeopleUrl = `https://swapi.co/api/people/`;
    const FilmUrl = `https://swapi.co/api/films/`;

    switch (character.name) {
      case "Luke Skywalker":
        axios.get(`${PeopleUrl}1/`)
          .then(response => Promise.all([
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}2/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}6/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}3/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}1/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}7/`)
          ])).then(result => result.map(values =>
            this.setState({
              movies: [
                ...this.state.movies,
                { title: values.data.title, release_date: values.data.release_date }
              ],
              loading: false
            })))
        break;

      case "C-3PO":
        axios.get(`${PeopleUrl}2/`)
          .then(response => Promise.all([
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}2/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}5/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}4/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}1/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}7/`)
          ])).then(result => result.map(values =>
            this.setState({
              movies: [
                ...this.state.movies,
                { title: values.data.title, release_date: values.data.release_date }
              ],
              loading: false
            })))
        break;

      case "Leia Organa":
        axios.get(`${PeopleUrl}unknown/`);
        break;

      case "R2-D2":
        axios.get(`${PeopleUrl}3/`)
          .then(response => Promise.all([
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}2/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}5/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}4/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}6/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}3/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}1/`),
            axios.get(`${FilmUrl}7/`)
          ])).then(result => result.map(values =>
            this.setState({
              movies: [
                ...this.state.movies,
                { title: values.data.title, release_date: values.data.release_date }
              ],
              loading: false
            })))
        break;

      default: return 'No list item'
    }
  }

  render() {
    const content = this.state.loading ?
      <div style={{ marginTop: "20px", padding: "20px" }}>"Loading..."</div> :
      <ul>
        {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
          <li key={movie.title}>
            {movie.title} - {movie.release_date}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

    const list = <ul>
      {
        charactersFile.characters.map(character => {
          return <li key={character.name} onClick={() => this.handleClick(character)}>{character.name}</li>
        })
      }
    </ul>

    return (
      <div className>
        {!this.state.render ? list : content}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

character.json

```
{
  "characters": [
    {
      "name": "Luke Skywalker",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
    },
    {
      "name": "C-3PO",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/2/"
    },
    {
      "name": "Leia Organa",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/"
    },
    {
      "name": "R2-D2",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/3/"
    }
  ]
}
```

error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `handleClick` call on `componentDidMount`

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleClick();  // calls handleClick(undefined)
  }
```

Comment: I have removed but still getting an error. check my updated answer above

Comment: Your code has many problems, you need to fetch items on componentDidMount without supplying any data to the function. Make your question minimal and simple as possible, moreover, dont update your question after every answer.

Comment: I want to handle different list item click that's why I have defined switch case in handleClick

Comment: The common way is to fetch items **first**, then handling them as you wish.

Comment: you mean fetch different li in componentDidMount() and handle it in handleClick method ?

Comment: in your example fetch the movies first and then the characters on click.

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: I don't know what your app's purpose, I just answered what you asked about the error, and please don't try to explain it in comments, either ask a new question and be more specific what you trying to achieve, refer to [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling function `handleClick` in your `componentDidMount` and not passing any argument, that makes `character` in your `handleClick` function definition, undefined.

And in its body, you're accessing its property, therefore you're getting the error above.

> Just remove `this.handleClick()` from your `componentDidMount`. Or if you want it to call, then pass some value in the function.

Another error I saw is you're not passing (defualt as true) to the className prop in your div element

```
<div className>
  {!this.state.render ? list : content}
</div>
```

Either give it some name or just remove it,

Second, the API request you're making, do not exist, it is clear 404 error in your console. In your case "Leia Organa", you're making `${PeopleUrl}unknown/` request, which just simply do not exist.

Comment: but we make api request in componentDidMount that's why I am calling from it

Comment: Right, but you have to pass some parameter as, which API request will be made is dependent upon the value of the character which you're not passing

Comment: no not same error after removing this.handleClick from componentDidMount I am not getting movie details when I click on li

Comment: Well, I can only see empty parentheses, pass something in the function when you're calling `handleClick` in `componentDidMount`

Comment: I have updated my answer but still I am getting an error. check my code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195028/discussion-between-siraj-and-riya).